# jQuery UI loaded but method fails in Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, backbone.js

**Problem:** jQuery UI is loaded, but calling a method fails.

**Description:** I am using Backbone for my web application. I am loading jQuery and jQuery UI as follows:

```
require (['jquery', 'app', 'biginteger', 'jqueryui'], function ($, App) {
    App.initialize();
});
```

In my view I do the following:

```
    if (jQuery.ui) {
        console.log('jQuery.ui is loaded');
        $('#pg_calendar').dialog();
    }
    else {
        console.log('jQuery.ui is not loaded');
    }
```

The browser prints 'jQuery.ui is loaded' to the console, but then the next statement fails with:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function
    at child.EventSelected (v_calendar.js:277)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
```

I would appreciate any ideas on how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by upgrading jQuery UI from v. 1.11.4 to 1.12.1.